# Having problem using 'pyttsx3' on Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: python, text-to-speech, python-3.8, ubuntu-20.04, pyttsx

I am on Ubuntu 20.04.
Tried the following code on Pycharm CE. Just to speak out "Hello World".

```py
import pyttsx3
pyttsx3.speak("Hello World!")
```

Getting the following output showing tons of errors. Please help!

```
 Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/masrafi/PycharmProjects/audio book/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pyttsx3/__init__.py", line 20, in init
    eng = _activeEngines[driverName]
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/weakref.py", line 131, in __getitem__
    o = self.data[key]()
KeyError: None

 During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

 Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/masrafi/PycharmProjects/audio book/audio book.py", line 2, in <module>
    pyttsx3.speak("Hello World!")
  File "/home/masrafi/PycharmProjects/audio book/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pyttsx3/__init__.py", line 28, in speak
    engine = init()
  File "/home/masrafi/PycharmProjects/audio book/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pyttsx3/__init__.py", line 22, in init
    eng = Engine(driverName, debug)
  File "/home/masrafi/PycharmProjects/audio book/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pyttsx3/engine.py", line 30, in __init__
    self.proxy = driver.DriverProxy(weakref.proxy(self), driverName, debug)
  File "/home/masrafi/PycharmProjects/audio book/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pyttsx3/driver.py", line 50, in __init__
    self._module = importlib.import_module(name)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/importlib/__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1014, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 991, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 975, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 671, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 783, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "/home/masrafi/PycharmProjects/audio book/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pyttsx3/drivers/espeak.py", line 9, in <module>
    from . import _espeak, toUtf8, fromUtf8
  File "/home/masrafi/PycharmProjects/audio book/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pyttsx3/drivers/_espeak.py", line 18, in <module>
    dll = cdll.LoadLibrary('libespeak.so.1')
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/ctypes/__init__.py", line 451, in LoadLibrary
    return self._dlltype(name)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/ctypes/__init__.py", line 373, in __init__
    self._handle = _dlopen(self._name, mode)
OSError: libespeak.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

 Process finished with exit code 1
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As the error points out: `OSError: libespeak.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory`, that library must be installed using

```
sudo apt install libespeak-dev
```

Answer (score 0):

just run below line in terminal

`sudo apt install libespeak1`

( for ubuntu )